# How are train breakdown events determined?

Tags: pocket-trains

Getting heavy into Pocket Trains lately. As one builds up it becomes increasingly more expensive to expand with more rail roads. I'm finding it difficult to build up cash due to an oddly common incident: train breakdowns. My question to you: What things affect how often a train breaks? Is it just the type of train? Or does number of engines and fuel cars have an effect?

I'm playing on iOS if that matters.

Comment: a new nimble game?! YES!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breakdowns are purely random.  Engines, fuel cars, length of travel, cargo, and so on have no effect on the breakdowns.

Comment: Do you have data to support this?

Comment: @A.Still Nothing I can show no. But I do remember seeing this in a "updatelog" by Nimble. Also, most PT guides claims it is random. [MMOsite](http://news.mmosite.com/content/2013-10-17/pocket_trains_guide_how_to_repair_trains.shtml) for example!